# Forward web request to another computer

Tags: iptables

I have one notebook and two servers:

- ip = 172.17.0.2 (I have installed nginx here)
- ip = 172.17.0.3 (There is nothing here, but I can ping 172.17.0.2 from here)

I open browser on my notebook, open

```
http://172.17.0.2
```

and get web page from Nginx.

Now I want to do something so, if I will open

```
http://172.17.0.3
```

in the browser this server forward my request 172.17.0.2 and return me same page back.

I have connected to  172.17.0.3 and make this changes:

```
root@6d2de436eef0:/# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
root@6d2de436eef0:/# iptables -t nat -F PREROUTING
root@6d2de436eef0:/# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.17.0.3 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2 
root@6d2de436eef0:/# iptables -F FORWARD
root@6d2de436eef0:/# iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
root@6d2de436eef0:/# iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -d 172.17.0.2 -j ACCEPT
root@6d2de436eef0:/# iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

Now I open

```
http://172.17.0.3,
```

but get nothing.  Why and how can I fix it ?

**Update**

Here is a result of tcpdump on 172.17.0.3 - http://pastebin.com/47MRWqXy

**Update 2**

Sorry, I gave you not full information.
Both servers 172.17.0.3 and 172.17.0.2 are docker containers.
Here is ifconfig on the host machine:

```
$ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:69:ac:53:70:53  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f0ee:53ff:feae:aa6c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:162525 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:278054 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:10471915 (10.4 MB)  TX bytes:436185034 (436.1 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:27:7a:e6  
          inet addr:172.20.0.136  Bcast:172.20.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f2de:f1ff:fe27:7ae6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16023892 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4007904 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8557520703 (8.5 GB)  TX bytes:484890281 (484.8 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Память:f8500000-f8520000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 82:ea:96:9d:48:88  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```